# Check if there is any 10 character word available in the string If Exist Extract the word

Tags: python, pandas

I have been looking to extract an 10 character word from the String if it exist.

Need to check if First 5 character are from a given list and last 3 character are numbers.

**Input Data (Data.xlsx) :**

```
Description                                                  Number

CHQ -AQBCN2Q546 from India Federation Pvt Ltd               
CHQN#DJBNK0Q329 from Indiana Basics Software Ltd -BC003
CASH-NJRQC5J987 from US Fertilizers LLP
CHQ - from India Bulls Pvt Ltd
CHQ -AQBCN2Q989 from India Bulls Pvt Ltd
CHQ -AQBCN2Q546 from India Federation Pvt Ltd

list_Character - ['AQBCN','PUCNQ','DJBNK','ADJBC','NJRQC']
```

**Expected Output:**

```
Description                                                          Number
    
CHQ -AQBCN2Q546 from India Federation Pvt Ltd                    AQBCN2Q546           
CHQN#DJBNK0Q329 from Indiana Basics Software Ltd -BC003          DJBNK0Q329
CASH-NJRQC5J987 from US Fertilizers LLP                          NJRQC5J987
CHQ - from India Bulls Pvt Ltd
CHQ -AQBCN2Q989 from India Bulls Pvt Ltd                         AQBCN2Q989
CHQ -AQCCN2Q546 from India Federation Pvt Ltd



Code:
import pandas as pd
import re

df = pd.read_excel(r'D:/Users/Data.xlsx')
list_Character - ['AQBCN','PUCNQ','DJBNK','ADJBC','NJRQC']
for i in df['Description']:
    list = re.findall("[ae]\w+", i)
```

I am not getting the way to find the solution, Please Suggest.

Comment: Can't you just split the string you get in i within your for loop and then check for numeric in the last element of resulting list and for the caracters in the first element ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```py
list_Character = ['AQBCN', 'PUCNQ', 'DJBNK', 'ADJBC', 'NJRQC']
regex = r'[#-]((?:' + r'|'.join(list_Character) + r')\w{5})\b'
df["Number"] = df["Description"].str.extract(regex)
```

Comment: Thanks For the Answer, But Needs to check if the First 5 character available in the variable [ list_String ] and "-" is not only the separator by which we can separate the values it can be anything, only we need to find the 10 character variable and if its first 5 character available in the given list.