# Check if there is any 12-character word available in the string. If available, extract the word

Tags: python, pandas

I have been looking to extract only a 12-character word from the string if it exists.

Need to check if first 5 characters are from a given list and check last 3 character are numbers.

**Input data (Data.xlsx):**

```
Description                                                  Number

CHQ -AQBCN222Q546 from India Federation Pvt Ltd               
CHQN#DJBNK220Q329 from Indiana Basics Software Ltd -BC003
CASH- NJRQC225J987^ from US Fertilizers LLP
CHQ - from India Bulls Pvt Ltd
AQBCN222Q989 from India Bulls Pvt Ltd
CHQ -AQCCN222Q546 from India Federation Pvt Ltd
CASH - AQBCN222Q546289 from India Federation Pvt Ltd

list_Character - ['AQBCN','PUCNQ','DJBNK','ADJBC','NJRQC']
```

**Expected output:**

```
Description                                                          Number
    
CHQ -AQBCN222Q546 from India Federation Pvt Ltd                    AQBCN222Q546           
CHQN#DJBNK220Q329 from Indiana Basics Software Ltd -BC003          DJBNK220Q329
CASH- NJRQC225J987^ from US Fertilizers LLP                        NJRQC225J987
CHQ - from India Bulls Pvt Ltd
AQBCN222Q989 from India Bulls Pvt Ltd                              AQBCN222Q989
CHQ -AQCCN222Q546 from India Federation Pvt Ltd
CASH - AQBCN222Q546289 from India Federation Pvt Ltd
```

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import re

df = pd.read_excel(r'D:/Users/Data.xlsx')
list_Character - ['AQBCN','PUCNQ','DJBNK','ADJBC','NJRQC']

regex = r'[#-]((?:' + r'|'.join(list_Character) + r')\w{5})\b'
df["Number"] = df["Description"].str.extract(regex)
```

I am not finding the solution.
I have tried getting the reference from [Check if there is any 10 character word available in the string If Exist Extract the word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74703291/check-if-there-is-any-10-character-word-available-in-the-string-if-exist-extract?noredirect=1#74703337) But it did not work.

Answer (score 1):

You can slightly modify the regex to remove the leading character match and match 7 extra characters:

```
list_Character = ['AQBCN','PUCNQ','DJBNK','ADJBC','NJRQC']

regex = r'((?:' + r'|'.join(list_Character) + r')\w{7})\b'
df["Number"] = df["Description"].str.extract(regex)
```

Output:

```
                                         Description        Number
0    CHQ -AQBCN222Q546 from India Federation Pvt Ltd  AQBCN222Q546
1  CHQN#DJBNK220Q329 from Indiana Basics Software...  DJBNK220Q329
2        CASH- NJRQC225J987^ from US Fertilizers LLP  NJRQC225J987
3                     CHQ - from India Bulls Pvt Ltd           NaN
4              AQBCN222Q989 from India Bulls Pvt Ltd  AQBCN222Q989
5    CHQ -AQCCN222Q546 from India Federation Pvt Ltd           NaN
6  CASH - AQBCN222Q546289 from India Federation P...           NaN
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer , Just want to understand what is the use of " r')\w{7})\b" used in the script.

Comment: The goal of your code is to craft a regex: `'((?:AQBCN|PUCNQ|DJBNK|ADJBC|NJRQC)\\w{7})\\b'` Here `\w{7}` matches seven "word" characters, and a word boundary: `\b`.